# What parameter should I pass this JavaScript function?

Tags: javascript, jquery, function

I am following [this tutorial](https://community.particle.io/t/reading-spark-variables-with-your-own-html-file/4148) that involves the use of JavaScript, which I have almost no experience with. In the code, the author calls the jQuery getJSON() function to retrieve JSON data using a HTTP GET request [from here](https://docs.particle.io/reference/api/#get-a-variable-value). If the request succeeds, it runs a specified function, and that function can take the data that is returned from the server as a parameter.

Here is the portion of code in question:

```
$.getJSON(requestURL, function(json) {
    document.getElementById("temp").innerHTML = json.result + "&deg; F";
    document.getElementById("temp").style.fontSize = "28px";
    document.getElementById("tstamp").innerHTML = json.coreInfo.last_heard;
});
```

If I want to declare the function that runs when the request succeeds separately, what should I use for the parameter that stores the response object?

This is what I want it to look like:

```
function onSuccess(json) {
    document.getElementById("temp").innerHTML = json.result + "&deg; F";
    document.getElementById("temp").style.fontSize = "28px";
    document.getElementById("tstamp").innerHTML = json.coreInfo.last_heard;
}

$.getJSON(requestURL, onSuccess()); //what should get passed into this function?
```

I apologize if this is an ignorant question, and thank you in advance.

Comment: Use `$.getJSON(requestURL, onSuccess);` - without the `()` after the function name.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll want to pass in the function itself as the parameter, not invoked:

`$.getJSON(requestURL, onSuccess);`

Answer (score -2):

Should be just as simple as:

```
$.getJSON(requestURL, onSuccess(data));
```

Comment: second argument should be a function